# SaveChangesAsync is still inserting synchronously in c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, entity-framework-core

I am writing a realtime application, where I receive data from a serial port, and need to save them to the database asynchronously. Here is the piece of code I am using:

```
private async Task SaveValToDb(ValueMonitored val, AppDbContext dbContext)
        {

            dbContext.ValueMonitored.Add(val);
            await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

private void serialPortReader_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e){
            .....
            SaveValToDb(pam_val, db_main);
            ....
}
```

However this does not to insert to it asynchronously. I know it because I measured the time it takes to do it in synch (when using SaveChanges()) and then in asynch.

Am I using the async wrong ?

Comment: How did you "measure the time" in a way that showed you if it was synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: You are not using `await` when calling an `async` method.  That's not good for a lot of reasons.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Asynchronous with task is slower than synchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52393047/c-sharp-asynchronous-with-task-is-slower-than-synchronous)

Comment: @CoryNelson I measured the time it takes when saving in sync, and then when saving in async, it is the same: more than 100ms.

Comment: @Zer0 why it is not good to use await with async ? How would you do it ?

Comment: @devNull not exactly. In the post you're citing, the guy is trying to do fast operations async, which is normal to cause more complexity and latency, while I am trying to insert to Db, which is time consuming, it should be done async.

Comment: @Spider well it sounds like you're expecting a single async call to execute in less time than its synchronous counterpart. And that post explains why that is not the case, regardless of what the async code is doing

Comment: Another way to look at it is that most of the execution time when saving changes is probably in the database. And simply changing how the application executes won't improve the performance in the database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209270/discussion-between-spider-and-devnull).